# installing python into basic Jenkins container

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

tldr) can i install python to my basic jenkins docker container, or do i have to use a different jenkins docker image from the start?

i installed a basic Jenkins container in docker with these lines in my cmd

```
1) docker pull jenkins/jenkins
2) docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v C:/xxxx/yyyy/jenkins_stuff:/var/jenkins_home jenkinsci/jenkins
```

when i go to plugs this is installed

[image: evidence of my python plugin installed to jenkins]

i then set up a freestyle project. I set it to pull from my github repository and in the build steps, execute shell i have....

```
lol=5
echo "hello world $lol" 
python3 thescript.py
```

it gives this output

```
Started by user jack flavell
Running as SYSTEM Building in workspace /var/jenkins_home/workspace/django_deploy_test The recommended git tool is: NONE No credentials specified

git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /var/jenkins_home/workspace/django_deploy_test/.git # timeout=10 Fetching changes from the remote Git repository git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/tgmjack/test_thing # timeout=10 Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/tgmjack/test_thing git --version # timeout=10 git --version # 'git version 2.30.2' git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/tgmjack/test_thing +refs/heads/:refs/remotes/origin/ # timeout=10 git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/main{commit} # timeout=10 Checking out Revision 773ffa8a9cb8fcf01e5f1387e47be2ab34866612 (refs/remotes/origin/main) git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10 git checkout -f 773ffa8a9cb8fcf01e5f1387e47be2ab34866612 # timeout=10 Commit message: "Create thescript.py" git rev-list --no-walk 773ffa8a9cb8fcf01e5f1387e47be2ab34866612 # timeout=10 [django_deploy_test] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins18201443432392254935.sh

lol=5
echo hello world 5 
hello world 5

python3 thescript.py /tmp/jenkins18201443432392254935.sh: 4: python3: not found Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure Finished: FAILURE
```

it seems to pull from git properly, but then cant do the python command.

i opened my jenkins container with docker exec -it and looked for python/ tried to install it, as shown below

```
$ which python3
$ apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 
Reading package lists... Done E: List directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial is missing. - Acquire (13: Permission denied) 
$ sudo apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 
/bin/sh: 3: sudo: not found 
$ python3 /bin/sh: 4: python3: not found
```

which shows me 3 problems

```
i cant do sudo

i cant install things without sudo

i dont have python
```

so my questions.

can i install python to the jenkins docker container i have? this is what ide prefer to do

alternativley do i have to use a different jenkins docker image with python allready installed?

Comment: You can enable su mode with `su -` and run the apt-get commands. You could also install sudo `apt-get install sudo -y` after using `su -`